# Scaling not applying for some reason.. (Video)

Tags: multiple-monitors, 17.10, scaling

Scaling is not applying on my 4k monitor if I got **Join Displays** mode on.

Works in **Single Display** mode fine.

Ubuntu 17.10

Checked and I'm running X11 display server, dunno if that has something to do with it.
There is no option when I restart or logout to select wayland as display server either.

Someone help me out please.

GPU: GTX 1080

Drivers: Nvidia 384.90

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-YsG9lRPkCc&feature=youtu.be)

EDIT: I don't mind If I cannot have Nvidia drivers, I can always just play on Windows, I just want the scaling to work on linux.